# How to Extract Instagram Data

Tags: web-scraping, instagram

I'm attempting to construct a Microsoft Access database of Instagram accounts, and want to extract the following data, among other things:

- Account name
- Number of followers
- Number of people followed
- Number of posts (and their dates)
- Number of likes of picture
- Number of comments on picture

I don't have any trouble constructing databases but want to know if there is an easier/faster way to get all the information without having to look through each individual picture/account and pick out the info.

Is Microsoft Access the best way to go with this? Are there better solutions?

Comment: Iv decided ill open the page source and pull out everything i need from there.

Comment: Access is about the worst choice for anything.

Answer (score 12):

Why not just look at the json data directly with url:

https://www.instagram.com//?__a=1

Comment: it works, its not open though, means you should be logged in to instagram to make this url work

Answer (score 9):

> Well if this question has 'web-Scraping' keyword then allow me to
>   share some information here..
>
> Instagram has a JavaScript JSON data in their html source while
>   display the user's information by link, like
>   https://www.instagram.com/user-account/. You can parse these data by
>   any scripting language and can get JSON data.
>
> **Instagram shows only 10 Posts once in Single Request**, You can see the
>   user's Basic information like **user name, biography, no of posts, no of
>   followers and following**. But, **if we need all likes and comments and
>   all images or likes and comments for each and every photo post**. Then
>   we have to click their '**`Load more`**' button.
>
> Load More request a Ajax Call include '**?max_id**' which gives you next
>   10 posts information. So you have to **create a Post loop to Send/Get
>   rest information until 'max_id' empty or null**.

Example Request: First page, `https://www.instagram.com/demo-user/`

Next Data Request: `https://www.instagram.com/demo-user/?max_id=1533276522`

and so on...

> Recently I had some spare time and I was angry on Instagram ;) So just
>   made a Script to solve all theses problems. This works on PHP and code
>   are well commented, so I don't think this cause any issue to
>   understand the application flow. You can see the script, how it works
>   & can use logic with any other language.

This comes from this [**GitHub Repository Code**](https://github.com/neerajsinghsonu/Instagram-Data-Scraper)

**&.. Yes, it doesn't required Instagram API or else.. :)**

Comment: Hello, I need to do this from Java as backend process. Can you tell how we can curl Load More (https://www.instagram.com/demo-user/?max_id=1533276522) as next url ?

Comment: I want to get hd_profile_pic_url_info. Is it possible with this

Comment: @Awadesh, That's a call from developers side. The "hd_profile_pic_url_info" is an option from users search but unfortunately, a user search is not working yet and that's why you will not able to get "hd_profile_pic_url_info". Well, you can give a try for tags (hashtag) with json data "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/flowers/?__a=1" and find "display_url" in json data. Hope that's help :)

Comment: When I requests the page of a user without login, it redirects to login page.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely check out Instagram's API, which can provide you all the public information you would want to scrape. You'll just need to write a script to make the proper API calls (provided below).

From Instagram's website:

> We do our best to have all our URLs be RESTful. Every endpoint (URL) may support one of four different http verbs. GET requests fetch information about an object, POST requests create objects, PUT requests update objects, and finally DELETE requests will delete objects.

You'll just need to have the **ACCESS-TOKEN** value for the relevant account ready when you use the URL in your code, and be able to unpack the json that Instagram returns to you with each GET request. If the data isn't *directly* available, you can always back it out indirectly. 
 - Account name
 - Number of followers
 - Number of people followed

Here's a great starting point: 
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users

And here's how you would make a call to an API in python:

```
#Python 2.7.6
#RestfulClient.py

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
import json

# Replace with the correct URL
url = "http://api_url"

# It is a good practice not to hardcode the credentials. So ask the user to enter credentials at runtime
myResponse = requests.get(url,auth=HTTPDigestAuth(raw_input("username: "), raw_input("Password: ")), verify=True)
#print (myResponse.status_code)

# For successful API call, response code will be 200 (OK)
if(myResponse.ok):

    # Loading the response data into a dict variable
    # json.loads takes in only binary or string variables so using content to fetch binary content
    # Loads (Load String) takes a Json file and converts into python data structure (dict or list, depending on JSON)
    jData = json.loads(myResponse.content)

    print("The response contains {0} properties".format(len(jData)))
    print("\n")
    for key in jData:
        print key + " : " + jData[key]
else:
  # If response code is not ok (200), print the resulting http error code with description
    myResponse.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: From what i understand the API requires the user to give you access to their (already public) information. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

This repo has it all : https://github.com/rarcega/instagram-scraper

Do read the options properly.

`instagram-scraper incindia -m 500 --media-metadata --include-location --media-types none`  gave me a json which has:

- a url to image of the media,
- type of media, number of views,
- number of likes, number of comments( --comment gives you all the comments too)

and more for me to explore yet.

You can also download all the media