# How to extract data from Instagram?

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

I am completely new to scripts and Digital Humanities, so any help would be most welcome. I need to find a way to extract data from instagram, namely

1. all posts that contain a certain tag

   - the content of this post
   - the username (and full name and bio if possible)
   - the location (if there is one)
   - the amount of likes and/or views
   - the date on which it was posted
2. all posts of a certain user

   - the content of this post
   - the username (and full name and bio if possible)
   - the location (if there is one)
   - the amount of likes and/or views
   - the date on which it was posted

I have no experience with web-scraping or Python, so I would be very grateful if someone could explain it in a way a layperson might understand or point me towards available scripts or other helpful  information/websites. I would need to export the data to a CSV-file.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have a look at scrapy python framework

Comment: Have a look at these
============
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405697/how-to-extract-instagram-data ----------------
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53103356/11339475
---------------

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you check their official API page?

https://www.instagram.com/developer/